# searching beautiful soup output without html tags

Tags: python, class, sorting, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a project that requires input from data that's displayed in a live flash graph (a data logging chart at `http://137.205.144.34/flash/index.html#menuIndex=1&accordionIndex=2&menuId=mimic1&menuStruct=S1R2M3C1H1`. As the html couldn't be accessed directly, I used Firebug to monitor my activity, and found the data I wanted stored at `http://137.205.144.34/services/unload.cmd?format=csvx&sched=&start=-240:00:00&id=75631&step=864`. However, when I try and access this url, it automatically saves a file (containing the data) to my pc, so I can't access the html source code. Using the url, I have used beautifulsoup to import the data, but i can't search or manipulate it using html tags as they are unknown. The only data i actually want is the latest hourly reading - one of ~ 1300 lines. And of that line, i only need the last value. Is there a way I could find the html tags? If not, what would be the best way to extract the bit of data I need?

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the BeautifulSoup code you've used so far, even if doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file you are downloading has no HTML in it. It is a comma-separated fle and you should use  the [csv module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to parse it.

This code will print the first item in each row (the item that contains the date and time):

```
import csv

with open('unload.cmd', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        print row[0]
```

This works assuming that you are using the file downloaded with the default name.

In order to first download the file programmatically, import it into a string, and then use it as a source file for the `csv.reader()`:

```
import urllib
import csv
import StringIO

url = 'http://137.205.144.34/services/unload.cmd?format=csvx&sched=&start=-240:00:00&id=75631&step=864'
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = f.read()

reader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data))
for row in reader:
    if row: print row[0]
```

Comment: Thanks. I now have an additional problem. The reading I want is to be used as input for a live graph of my own. If I use a file instead of the url I don't see how that will be possible. What would you suggest?